# SELinux keeps blocking my Apache instance

Tags: centos, selinux

I am using CentOS 7 and have set up a duplicate Apache instance using the systemd structure there.

I can get both Apaches to run if I use setenforce 0. However, when I setenforce 1, the new Apache won't start.

I did my best to go through all the files I created and I have copied the SELinux type across using "ls -Z" and then chcon to the same as httpd.

The failure message I am getting is:

```
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.123185 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24944] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.124434 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 24944] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.146830 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 24944] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.147901 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 24944] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.147983 2016] [core:error] [pid 24944] (13)Permission denied: AH00099: could not create /etc/httpd-bobby/httpd-bobby.pid
[Thu Jun 23 23:51:24.148000 2016] [core:error] [pid 24944] AH00100: httpd-bobby: could not log pid to file /etc/httpd-bobby/httpd-bobby.pid
```

But the location has the httpd context:

```
[root~]# ls -Z /etc | grep httpd
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 httpd
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 httpd-bobby
```

I know it is SELinux because it works with setenforce 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple httpd contexts and this isn't the right one.

The directory in which the pid file goes should have the context `httpd_var_run_t` .

I'd recommend against putting it in /etc and create one in /var/run.

To set the correct context permanently for example for /var/run/httpd-bobby:

`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_run_t "/var/run/httpd-bobby(/.*)?" &&
restorecon /var/run/httpd-bobby`

Comment: You don't need to add a new regex. Policy allows httpd_t to write to var_run_t so just creating /var/run/httpd-bobby with suitable permissions should to the trick.

Comment: @Iain Thanks, didn't fully check the policy